# Cannot login to keycloak admin console when running in domain cluster mode

Tags: keycloak

Following the [documentation](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html) guide, I have booted up a master and slave and I can see it connected via the logs:

```
Boot up master
$ domain.sh --host-config=host-master.xml
Boot up slave
$ domain.sh --host-config=host-slave.xml
```

I've also followed the steps to set up the admin user via the add-user.sh. Further research indicated that I should use the add-user-keycloak.sh script to add an initial admin user:

```
./add-user-keycloak.sh -u john
Press ctrl-d (Unix) or ctrl-z (Windows) to exit
Password: 
Added 'john' to '../standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json', restart server to load user
```

Reran the master and slave, but cannot login to admin console.

However, what's interesting is when I tried to boot up in standalone mode I was able to the admin console as john:

```
./standalone.sh
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something (most likely) that's not in the documentation?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, hope this helps somebody.

Before you start in domain cluster mode:

```
./domain --host-config=host-master.xml
./domain --host-config=host-slave.xml
```

you must first create the admin so you can log in to admin console using the --sc tag, otherwise add-user-keycloak.sh only adds the admin user for the standalone mode. To do that:

```
./add-user-keycloak.sh --sc ../domain/servers/server-one/configuration -u john -p password
```

if configuration folder does not exist, then create the directory.

Answer (score 2):

The `./add-user-keycloak.sh` script seems to be a little outdated. Currently (as of Keycloak 12.0.2 version) it creates keycloak-add-user.json file in `./domain/configuration/` directory - **That is wrong!**

The file should be in `./domain/servers/server-one/configuration`.
Now you just have to move the file to that directory, restart the server and it should work properly.

**I found this solution on this 2-year old email thread:**

https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-January/012642.html